# How can I run JWPlayer on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, jwplayer

with the code below, the video plays smoothly on desktop but not on mobile.
It works very fast on the desktop device, but when the page is opened on the mobile, the loader returns for a long time and then returns error 224003.
I pull the related video from external server with php and open it using http_range. I think it might be about

```
var Player = jwplayer("Player");
            Player.setup({

    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    preload: "auto",
    fullscreen: "true",
    repeat: "false",
    hlslabels: {
        "1700": "720p",
        "600": "480p",
        "256": "240p"
    },
    captions: {
        backgroundOpacity: 0,
        fontSize: 22,
        edgeStyle: "uniform"
    },
    fallback: "false",
    primary: "html5",
    androidhls: true,
    wmode: "opaque",
    playbackRateControls: [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2],
    sources: [{
            file:"https://video.cccc.org/cccc.mp4",
            label: "480p",
            type: "video/mp4"
      },{
            file:"https://video.ccccc.org/ccccc.mp4",
            label: "720p",
            type: "video/mp4",
'default': 'true'
      },{
            file:"https://video.ccccc.org/ccccccc.mp4",
            label: "1080p",
            type: "video/mp4"
      }],
     image: "https://video.ccccccc.org/srv43/assets/cccccc-video-onu.jpg",
    skin: {
        name:"alaska"
    },
    abouttext: "Player",
    aboutlink: "https://ccccccc.org/",
    startparam: "start",
    provider: "http",
});
```

Comment: You can check your errors here: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-player-errors-reference. Anyways it seems your file format is not supported by the mobile device. **(1)** You say mobile but are you testing on Android or iOS? Have you tried a different device also? **(2)** Why setting `androidhls: true` if your source files are MP4? HLS is for live streams so try removing that option or else setting it as `androidhls: false,` **(3)** If still failing to play then proivide a link to the smallest file for others to test.

Comment: I tried it didn't work

Comment: It didn't work where (Android or iOS)? Does [this file](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) work (play) if loaded from your own server? Finally if you can't provide a testable file then at least download **mediaInfo** tool and tell us what it reports about your video file's codec settings...

Comment: I used mediainfo and the result is as in the link: https://ghostbin.co/paste/pw95x

Comment: Your video settings seem fine so I could not see an issue to reply about. I noticed though you said that you use `http_range`, does that mean you slice the file and try to play that cut segment (_eg:_ from middle to the ending?) ... To play an MP4 file correctly it must have a header called MOOV followed by the a/v media bytes in the MDAT section. The header tells the video player where and which frames are keyframes and which bytes are sound or video etc, if you slice then you must create a new header (edited from original input) to reflect the new byte positions of the a/v frames